# Comparing CFA models (AIC)

Tags: model, aic, confirmatory-factor, nested-models

I wonder whether I can use AIC for model comparison in this scenario:

Model 1: 
A = a + b + c 
B = d + e + f 
C = g + h + i

Model 2: 
A = a + b + c 
B = d + e + f 
(The third factor with his indicators is missing)

The AIC for the second model is much lower. I’m unsure of applicability, because a latent variable and three indicators are missing.

Comment: If you use R with lavaan package then you simple apply _anova(fit1, fit2)_ where _fit1_ and _fit2_ are the correspondent models created by _lavaan::cfa_ command. There is no problem if you do not have a latent variable.

Comment: Thank you. I also considered that model 2 is nested in model 1, because parameters are dropped. However, I can’t find literature about comparing models that differ in their number of factors and in the number of indicators. Are you sure, that the models are nested?  

Further, I get the following warning, when I use the anova()-function:
In lavTestLRT(object = <S4 object of class "lavaan">, SB.classic = TRUE,  :
 lavaan WARNING: some models are based on a different set of observed variables

Comment: I think that I should reconsider my advice. At first glance, since all the terms of the (smaller) model 2 occur in the larger model 1, it looked ok to say that the models are nested, however this is not the case when the two models have different observed variables. Please take a look at this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lavaan/Ya3Ak4AiTkQ) discussion of lavaan google group with subject "lavaan WARNING: some models are based on a different set of observed variables" and the advices therein.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. It seems that I can't easily compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The AIC is a function of the loglikelihood and loglikelihoods are only comparable across the same data set, i.e., all the same variables and sample. Thus, you can use AIC to compare these non-nested models:

```
Model 1:
A = a + b + c
B = d + e + f
C = g + h + i
```

and

```
Model 2:
A = a + b + e
B = c + d + h
C = f + g + i
```

because the exact same data set is used for both models.

In your example, the columns of variables differ, making the loglikelihoods incomparable.